# Getting started with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

there is a new book about intellij , Getting started with IntelliJ IDEA , i find tome website but can not find anyone , anyone has this book please send me ?

Answer (score 2):

<soapbox-rant>

Unless I am misunderstanding you... you are asking someone to illegally send you a copy of [this book](http://www.packtpub.com/getting-started-with-intellij-idea/book) in e-book format. That's rather unethical. And it goes against the spirit, if not the rules, of StackOverflow. Not to mention the law. Authors work hard to write books. I'm sure this one is no exception. I'm sure you wouldn't like it if people stole things from you and/or your company. You'd be out of a job soon and living on the streets. If you want a copy of the book -- e-book or physical book -- you can buy it.

</soapbox-rant>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any really good books, but there is a very good overview demo to get started with:

```
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/overview.html
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I guess [**this**](http://www.packtpub.com/getting-started-with-intellij-idea/book) is the one you refer to. As you can see, it should(or already) out this month, but you'll have to wait, till you can download it from web for free. If you would like to master this program, you should just code and in time you'll know pretty much that you need.